# opencv java resize does not work

Tags: java, android, opencv

I am doing android development in java with opencv.  I am trying to get OpenCv Imgproc.resize() to zoom in on an image, but it does not change the magnification.  It seems to just copy the same image from a source to destination Mat with no changes.  Any help would be appreciated.  Thanks.  My code is:

```
Mat src = new Mat(bitmap.getWidth(), bitmap.getHeight(), CvType.CV_8UC3);

Utils.bitmapToMat(bitmap, src, true);

Mat dst = new Mat((int)(src.cols()*1.5), (int)(src.rows()*1.5), CvType.CV_8UC3);

Imgproc.resize(src, dst, dst.size()); //resize image

resizedBitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(dst.cols(),  dst.rows(), Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);

Utils.matToBitmap(dst, resizedBitmap);

imageView.setImageBitmap(resizedBitmap);
```

Comment: Please format your code using indentation, as per site guidelines. It makes it much easier to read.

Comment: I apologize for not indenting my code correctly.  I'll make sure I do so next time.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem before and I solve it by 
put those lines in the code :-

```
 public class MainActivity  extends Activity {

       //Put your code here ...


        static {
                System.loadLibrary("opencv_java");
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Mat dst = new Mat(); //no, you don't have to pre-allocate it. this is no more C.
Imgproc.resize(src, dst, new Size(src.cols()*1.5), (int)(src.rows()*1.5)) ); //resize image
// or:
Imgproc.resize(src, dst, new Size(), 1.5, 1.5); //resize image
```

Comment: Thank you for this answer.  This code does not work in my case, and I've discovered why.  I wrote a java test program to run on my PC, and the resize method worked perfectly.  This problem apparently only occurs with an android application.  I'm wondering if maybe there's a conflict between the opencv resize method and maybe a native android resize method.  I still have this problem, but the cause is apparently due to the android platform.  Is there by any chance an android guru who might have any ideas?  Thanks again to everyone for this assistance.

Comment: berak, you've given me the answer I need.  Thank you.  It turns out the problem was I needed to crop the Mat before I could resize it back to 100% of the screen again.  berak told me the resize code was correct, so I realized I needed to look at something else.  Thanks again.

Comment: mSource = inputFrame.gray();
Imgproc.resize(mSource, mDest, new Size(), 0.5, 0.5);
return mDest; The results that i get is black screen. Am I missing something?